# how would you detect loop in binary tree

Tags: binary-tree

How would you detect loop in binary tree. As an example in below image Node 5 is Illegal node. One way is to find the number of edges and node. edges should be n -1.

[image]

Comment: Please include some information about the language you are using and what you have attempted so far.

Comment: @Piyush - ref. to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree for complete definition of the Binary Tree, I hope you know it. So, if each node is having atmost two children its a binary tree.

Comment: Also, your question is not cleared about like what you want to achieve and in which language you want to do it. I can write a program of Binary tree in C++, C# and few more languages, but please revise your question for more clarity.

Comment: @gaurav irrespective of programming language, the question is how do you validate the given tree is binary tree or not. there are so many program available to check whether tree is BST or not. but this question is for binary tree. consider if two different nodes have same child node which is invalid binary tree.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, i have updated the question.

Comment: Traverse the binary tree and keep track of which nodes you have seen.  If you encounter a child which has been seen before, then throw an exception.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen good suggestion but what if tree has duplicate node data ? even if we consider no duplicate data it will require O(N) space, can we do it without any space ?

Comment: I don't see any way of not having state to know where you have been.  I am prepared to be corrected though.

Answer (score 1):

We could do any type of traversal like preorder, postorder or inorder and check if any nodes comes more than once in traversal sequence. If yes, then there is a loop.

Answer (score -2):

You can traverse through the tree and check if each parent has two or less number of child, otherwise it's not a binary tree.

Recursive way:

```
flag = true;
traverse(Node node){
    if(node == null || !flag)
        return;
    //Check for more than two children, if yes not binary tree, exit
    if(node.getChilds().length > 2){
        flag = false;
        return;
    }
    // Go through each nodes
    for(Node child : node.getChilds()) {
        traverse(child);
    }
}
```

Note: Better will be using a non recursive way, where you can exit the loop as soon as you find more than two children.

Comment: it wont work when one child node has two parent node. I have added a image to the question.

Comment: this will not detect a loop